# Windows 7/Ubuntu does not boot after installation.

Tags: installation, wubi, data-recovery

I installed Ubuntu on Windows 7 now neither OS boots up.

How can I recover Windows OS and uninstall Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Boot up Windows install DVD, & choose `Repair your Computer`

open command prompt and Run the Following commands

```
bootrec.exe/fixboot
```

next

```
bootrec.exe/fixmbr
```

Reboot to windows and use  a partitioning program to remove Ubuntu's partition